# $x^3 +y^2 +z =100z+10y+x$ What is the largest and smallest integer that satisfies this equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

$x^3 + y^2 +z=\overline{zyx}$, where $\overline{zyx}$ denotes the sequence of the digits.

$x^3 +y^2 +z =100z+10y+x$,where $x,y,z>0$

The maximum value of $x$, $y$, $z$ individually can only be $9$.

$\text{Maximum value}= 9^3 + 9^2 + 9 = 819$

So, $100z+10y+z<819$

Then I'm lost here a bit. What do I do next?

Comment: How is a small value defined? Your solution is 3-dimensional. Do you mean the solution with smallest euclidean norm?

Comment: The smallest integer that satisfies the equation?

Comment: why is the max value 9? why not $10^3 +10^2+10=100*10+10*10+10$?

Comment: $ x^3 + y^2 +z =zyx$,where zyx denotes the sequence of the digits.Sorry,I forget to add this part to the question.

Comment: Also if the max value is 9 and the smallest values are 1 then you can do a finite exhaustive search in not to much time.

Comment: because x,y,z are digits themselves? and z is in  the hundreds,y in tens and x in ones

Comment: FindInstance[{z^3 + y^2 + z == x + 10 *y + 100 *z, 9 > z > 0, 
  9 > y > 0, 9 > x > 0}, {z, y, x}, Integers, 10] returned 0 solutions so unless i'm mistaken to the question thats the answer

Comment: The answer to the largest is $598$ I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$x^3+y^2+z=100z+10y+x$$

$$x(x+1)(x-1)=y(10-y)+99z$$

No needs to check $x=1$ and $y$ have symmetrical sense (e.g. if $y=1$ satisfies so as $y=9$).

Also, $9\leq y(10-y) \leq 25$ hence $$9(1+11z)\leq x(x+1)(x-1) \leq 25+99z$$

$$108\leq x(x+1)(x-1) \leq 916$$

$$\because \quad 3\times 4\times 5 < 108 < 4\times 5\times 6 \implies x\geq 5$$

Now,

$$4\times 5\times 6 \leq y(10-y)+99z \leq 8\times 9\times 10$$

$$120-25 \leq 99z \leq 720-9 \implies 1\leq z \leq 7$$

> This can further confine to $5\leq x \leq 8$; and in turn, furthermore confine to $1\leq z\leq 5$.

Simple search gives

$$\overline{zyx}=135,\, 175,\, 518,\, 598$$

Comment: Sorry but I don't really understand the second paragraph. Why does $x$ and $y$ have symmetrical sense?

Comment: @Arc Neoepi Only $y$ has symmetrical sense (arround 5).

Comment: Why does $y$ have symmetrical sense and no need to check $x=1$ for?Is it $x=1$,then $0=y(10-y) +99z$?

Comment: @Arc Neoepi If $y$ is a solution then $10-y$ is a also solution and vice versa (5 is a point of symmetry).  Yes, don't need to check as right side is always greater then zero.

Comment: What is this 'symmetrical sense?'why is 5,being the point of symmetry do important?

Comment: @Arc Neoepi You do not need to check separately two values which are equally distant to 5, but only one of them.

Comment: Then how about the part of $ 9\leq y(10-y) \leq 25$ ?

Comment: @ArcNeoepi, $y(10-y)=25-(y-5)^2\leq 25$ and $1\leq y \leq 9 \implies 1\times 9 \leq y(10-y)$.  Note that the graph of $Y=X(10-X)$ is a parabola that concave down, symmetrical about $X=5$.

Comment: $y(10-y)=25-(y-5)^2\leq 25$ .How did the $\leq 25$ and $(y-5)^2$ pop out?Sorry I'm in Secondary 3 or High school year 1 or 2

Comment: It's called **completing the square**.  $y(10-y)=10y-y^2=\color{red}{25}-(\color{red}{25}-10y+y^2)=25-(5-y)^2$ and $(5-y)^2\geq 0 \implies -(5-y)^2\leq 0$ (Note that $a^2\geq 0$ for any real values of $a$.)  We can do so for any quadratic function $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c=a\left(x-\frac{b}{2a}\right)^2+\left( c-\frac{b^2}{4a^2} \right)$.  Anyhow, the question is tedious for a junior form students.

Comment: I see.I didn't know you can use completing the square like this.Mind blown!$108\leq x(x+1)(x-1) \leq 916$ ,how do you know the value of $z$?Where did it go to?

Comment: Firstly, for $x\geq 1$, $x(x+1)(x-1)$ is strict increasing with $x$.  Secondly, $1\leq z \leq 9$ and combining the range of $y(10-y)$ you can find the possible range of $x$.  In turn, you can find the range of $z$.  The colored box gives the best bounds.  The rest is trial-and-error.

Answer (score 0):

Brute force solution using your computer and vbscript:

> For i = 111 to 999
>   $\ \ \ \ \ $    x = i Mod 10
>   $\ \ \ \ \ $    y = ((i-x) \ 10) Mod 10
>   $\ \ \ \ \ $    z = i \ 100
>   $\ \ \ \ \ $    If (( z+y^2+x^3) = i) Then Msgbox (i)
>   Next

Result: 135,175,518,598

However Ng Chung Tak's solution is much more elegant.